# How to integrate Sphinx with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, sphinx

Can anyone help me out please.

I am using Laravel 4, I have followed the tutorials below:

1. http://packalyst.com/packages/package/mnshankar/sphinxql
2. http://registry.autopergamene.eu/package/scalia-sphinxsearch

I didn't get proper solution. It's not working for me. I have successfully started the Sphinx Service it's working in `CorePHP`. I need it in `Laravel`.

Comment: so *what* is not working for you? do you have any error output if any?

Comment: they said add `mnshankar/sphinxql` to `composer.json`. I tried like this `c:/xampp/htdocs/myproject>composer require "mnshankar/sphinxql:1.0"`

Comment: its showing the msg  **installation failed**

Comment: Maybe it's a typo mystake but it should be "mnshankar/sphinxql": "1.0".

Comment: I tried  this statement `"mnshankar/sphinxql": "1.0"` but it's showing error. DO you have idea about how to add `mnshankar/sphinxql` to `composer.json`

Comment: `composer require "mnshankar/sphinxsql" "1.0"` should add it to your `composer.json`. Otherwise, it's just a file, and you can add the entry yourself.